# Ampps Installation Issues PHP modules

Tags: php, installation, ampps

I downloaded the latest [Ampps windows version](http://www.ampps.com/download) and during installation received many PHP Warnings 'Unable to Initalize module...'. The .dll files are in the correct location but I'm not sure why it won't initiate the .dlls and why the API's are mismatched.

```
Failed loading C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps\php-5.6\ioncube_loader_win_5.6.dll
Xdebug requires Zend Engine API version 220131226.
The Zend Engine API version 220121212 which is installed, is outdated.

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: bz2: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20131226\nPHP    compiled with module API=20121212\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps\\php-5.6\\ext\\php_curl.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: fileinfo: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20131226\nPHP    compiled with module API=20121212\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: gd: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20131226\nPHP    compiled with module API=20121212\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: gettext: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20131226\nPHP    compiled with module API=20121212\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: gmp: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20131226\nPHP    compiled with module API=20121212\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps\\php-5.6\\ext\\php_imap.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mbstring: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20131226\nPHP    compiled with module API=20121212\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: exif: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20131226\nPHP    compiled with module API=20121212\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mysql: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20131226\nPHP    compiled with module API=20121212\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mysqli: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20131226\nPHP    compiled with module API=20121212\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps\\php-5.6\\ext\\php_openssl.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pdo_mysql: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20131226\nPHP    compiled with module API=20121212\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pdo_sqlite: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20131226\nPHP    compiled with module API=20121212\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: soap: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20131226\nPHP    compiled with module API=20121212\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: sockets: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20131226\nPHP    compiled with module API=20121212\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: sqlite3: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20131226\nPHP    compiled with module API=20121212\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: tidy: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20131226\nPHP    compiled with module API=20121212\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: xmlrpc: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20131226\nPHP    compiled with module API=20121212\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps\\php-5.6\\ext\\php_xsl.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: com_dotnet: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20131226\nPHP    compiled with module API=20121212\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mongo: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20131226\nPHP    compiled with module API=20121212\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0
[Tue Apr 02 17:54:28.999194 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7712:tid 828] AH00455: Apache/2.4.27 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0f PHP/5.6.31 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Apr 02 17:54:28.999194 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7712:tid 828] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC15 Server built: Jul  7 2017 11:43:51
[Tue Apr 02 17:54:28.999194 2019] [core:notice] [pid 7712:tid 828] AH00094: Command line: 'apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/apache'
[Tue Apr 02 17:54:28.999194 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7712:tid 828] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 2992
Failed loading C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps\php-5.6\ioncube_loader_win_5.6.dll
Xdebug requires Zend Engine API version 220131226.
The Zend Engine API version 220121212 which is installed, is outdated.

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: com_dotnet: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20131226\nPHP    compiled with module API=20121212\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mongo: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20131226\nPHP    compiled with module API=20121212\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0
[Tue Apr 02 18:00:58.604316 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 15976:tid 668] AH00455: Apache/2.4.27 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0f PHP/5.6.31 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Apr 02 18:00:58.604316 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 15976:tid 668] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC15 Server built: Jul  7 2017 11:43:51
[Tue Apr 02 18:00:58.604316 2019] [core:notice] [pid 15976:tid 668] AH00094: Command line: 'apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/apache'
[Tue Apr 02 18:00:58.609313 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 15976:tid 668] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 6388
Failed loading C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps\php-5.6\ioncube_loader_win_5.6.dll
Xdebug requires Zend Engine API version 220131226.
The Zend Engine API version 220121212 which is installed, is outdated.
```

Comment: I have face same issue can you find any solution about this.

Comment: I was not able to fix these errors. However this forced me to look at other options and found a little gem called 'Laragon' recommend checking it out. https://laragon.org/